# The use of Hall algebras in physics

Tags: particle-physics, mathematical-physics, mathematics, representation-theory

I asked the same question in [mo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111868). I think maybe here there are more physics guys to help me.

I once read a statement (not memorized precisely) that a certain physics quantity between two states of charge $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively could be computed by running over the states of charge $d_1+d_2$ which is the extension of the original two states. Therefore we need to consider some [Hall algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_algebra) on a moduli space.

I couldn't find that literature any more, so I am not sure that this statement is correct. Could anyone help me to make clear this sort of things?

My questions are:

1. What is the basic physics setting of this story?
2. Why is this "extension" important?
3. If this is not correct, what is the correct statement/why do physicists care about Hall algebras?

PS: I think these questions are also related to the representations of particles, and the decomposition of particles.

Answer (score 1):

The MathOverflow [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111868/the-use-of-hall-algebras-in-physics/111900#111900) really is good:  Harvey & Moore's papers are pretty much required reading in this subject.